# "Learn to code" vs. "Learn coding"

Tags: meaning, differences

Is there a semantic difference between `learn to code` and `learn coding`? Can both forms be used interchangeably?

Comment: I would vote to close as NR

Comment: Come to think of it, I suppose the question could be expanded to a more general case: `learn to drive` vs. `learn driving`, `learn to golf` vs `learn golfing`, `learn to pierce ears` vs `learn ear piercing`, etc.  But the latter phrases sound awkward - so, perhaps: `learn to box` vs `study boxing`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there's a slight difference.  I'm going to explain by comparing *learn to program* with *learn programming*.

To *learn to program* means the student (or trainee) will learn how to write software.  If the training is successful, the student will become a proficient programmer.

To *learn programming*, on the other hand, means the student will learn *about* programming.  This might include, for example, programming principles, theory, and best practices.  If the training is successful, the student will have a better understanding of the various nuances of programming.

There is a lot of overlap, no doubt, but they are not exactly the same thing (not in my mind, at least).

A programmer must *learn to code*.  A software project manager might benefit from *learning programming*.  After all, even if a manager never programs, such knowledge might help managers better understand the challenges faced by their programming teams.

Comment: nice (in both senses) distinction!

Comment: -1, I disagree totally.  *Learn programming* and *learn to program* are the same IMHO; neither means *learn about programming*.

Comment: @Jez: Fair enough. We weren't given a lot of context, and I merely explained how it struck me, when pressed to consider possible differences.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, *learn coding* (or *learn programming*) may mean *learn **while** coding*, i.e. learn by doing, learn from experience (as opposed to learning from books or taking classes).  :-)