# Code vs. Coding

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, software

Since a few years I hear and read the term *the coding* when they mean *the code* more and more often. Personally this sounds so absolutely wrong to me and I think it is.

A few examples:

- "Can I have your coding?"
- "The coding is buggy"
- "The coding (containing the invalid instructions) was done years ago"
- "In this coding you can find xyz"

I would appreciate it if someone (other than me for strategic reasons) could clearly and as concisely as possible summarize when to use:

- the term *coding*
- the term *code*

so that I can point people to this question every time I hear/read this and they immediately understand the difference (and hopefully start using those terms in their (original) meaning).

PS: My question aims at the context of software development exclusively (so e.g. code as in cryptography or security or other fields are out of context).

Edit: Enhanced 3rd example because the semantics were unclear.

Comment: Not to deny the reality of your claim, but _I_ have never heard this misusage.

Comment: Here a few examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22give+me+the+coding%22&oq=%22give+me+the+coding%22

Comment: This may be related. I've found that there are some people (including myself) that treat "code" as a mass noun, and others as a singular. 

An example of the first style: "I've got some buggy code to fix before noon." 

An example of the second style: "Give me a code that does the signal manipulation."

Comment: The third example does not fit the other three. In that example, _coding_ is actually the better term to use: coding is done, code is written. You wouldn’t say that anyone “did the code” years ago; they either did the coding or they wrote the code.

Comment: @Janus Agree... bad example because it can be interpreted in both ways (my intention was "The code was written years ago")

Comment: @user888379 I've never seen that usage in connection with program code, and it feels quite wrong. "A code" is something quite different: a code for Germany is "de".

Comment: I would speculate (though I can't confirm it) that most of the cited examples of "give me the coding" are Indian English: or at any rate, not British or American native speakers.

Comment: I don't find a good reference but they are both used for both noun (product) and verb (process).  Coding is more general.  If someone said this is bad coding it is more likely to mean bad practices in general.  This code is bad could be just short segment with a minor error.

Comment: Where are you located? Are native English speakers saying this? Only #3 is acceptable to me as a native speaker of AmE (who does code daily).

Comment: this sounds almost certainly like a symptom of english as a second language

Comment: @AzorAhai: as an AmE speaker who also codes daily, If have encountered forms of the others. Its it bit of a shibboleth though; in my experience, anything other than #3 means that the speaker is a) old, b) doesn't know anything about computers or programming and c) is either family of mine or ranks above me in the business hierarchy.

Comment: @ Azor/Michael I'm working with international teams. But granted - I cannot remember a single native english speaker saying/writing this. I observe it frequently when talking/reading/writing with persons from european or eastern countries.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has been programming since 1968, the first and 4th examples are a little odd, but the second and third are perfectly normal, in a reasonable context.

Comment: Your would be better occupied with correcting your own English. "Since a few years" works in many languages but not English. "For many years I have heard…" And your sentence is ungrammatical when you say "they mean…" without any previous noun for the pronoun to refer to. You need to have some antecedent like "I have heard people say…". Finally an English Language site is not the ammunition for your campaign. Research the published output of large US software companies for evidence. You are a computer person. You should know how to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about English usage in a particular professional sphere, which can be beter answered by applying the technology of that discipline.

Answer (score 14):

*Code* is the result of a *coding* process. The *coding* (process) of an algorithm results in executable *code* (product).

There is a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67830/learn-to-code-vs-learn-coding?rq=1) about *learn to code* vs *learn coding*. In that case they are equivalent, as they are both verbs.

In your example *The coding was done years ago*, the usage is arguably correct when you talk about the process. With a different verb it would not work:

**The coding was written years ago*
*The code was written years ago*

**Edit**: Just for completeness, *to code* is also a verb. *A code* is a mapping between symbols, eg [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) mapping *e* to '.' and *t* to '-', or [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) mapping 32 to ' ' and 65 to 'A'.

Comment: *"code"* is also a verb.  i'm gonna code up an algorithm.

Comment: Actually, "code" and "coding" are different forms of the *same* verb.

Comment: Ultimately they are all related, of course. _Coding_ as in the example sentences of the question is not a verb, but a noun, derived from the verb (which in turn might be derived from the noun _code_ again).

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to tell your friend that you are going to write a program that would find the solution to a quadratic equation.
So you can say,

> I am going to code a program that would find the solution to a quadratic equation.

Or you can say,

> I am planning on coding a program that would find the solution to a quadratic equation.

You can also say,

> I am going to write a program that would find the solution to a quadratic equation.

Also, "code" may be used in a sense that you are going to write the program but haven't started yet. "Coding" in that sense is used when you have stated to program.

Answer (score 1):

A *code* is a product, and *coding* is an action.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source to support your answer.

Comment: My problem with this answer is the use of *"A"*, I would always choose *"Code is..."*. Similarly the use of *"I wrote some codes..."* bothers me (when talking about developing using a modern development language that generally consists of statements), and prefer *"I wrote some code..."* (which is discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209724/a-code-or-some-code))

Comment: @NickA here's why: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context).

Comment: @JJJ Ah yes, thank you, that's a much better link than the one I gave

Answer (score 1):

*Code* is the main word of programming, and *coding* is the process of programming. This is the really important difference between *code* and *coding*.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try myself because I think I have a slightly more formal answer than the answers provided up to now (Oliver and Elsa are going into the same direction but the answers are a little bit vague in my opinion). I'll let the voters decide on the final accepted answer later.

My try:

1. "Code" is a noun ("here is my source code")
2. "to code" is the verb (I code, you code,...) and the present participle  is "coding".
3. "Coding" is a Gerund (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund): a verb form that functions as a noun

The intention in the examples is to talk about the (code) object/thing and not about the (coding) action/process (Oliver and Elsa mentioned this as well and I think this is an important distinction). Therefore the noun should be used which is "code" and the examples would be correct if the word "Code" would have been used:

- "Can I have your (source) code?"
- "The (source) code is buggy"
- "The (source) code (containing the invalid instructions) was done years ago"
- "In this (source) code you can find xyz"

So why would someone use "coding" instead ? I assume this comes from the Gerund mentioned in 3) because the Gerund by definition is *used like a noun*. But the meaning of the Gerund is similar to the verb because it aims at the action/process and this is not what the examples try to express. Therefore the usage of "coding" in the examples is wrong.

Comment: When you read the 1st sentence in my question I stated "...I hear and read the term 'the coding' when they mean' the code' "

Comment: One would use "coding" when the subject under discussion is the *manner* of programming rather than the *product* of programming. "The coding is buggy" means that there are aspects of the way the code is written which are apt to lead to bugs -- poor formatting, poor variable naming, lack of "structure", etc.

Answer (score -1):

One shouldn't use the words "code" or "coding", these should be limited to the output of the compiler, and what the compiler does.

What one does when programming is that one "writes sources". A programmer is writing sources for people, mostly. When needed, the compiler transforms the source into code. It also means a programmer is a writer, not a "coder".

Why? "code" and "coding" has meanings such as "hiding", "obscuring", "ciphering". A programmer is not trying to mask his work, but on the contrary to make it as clear and as easy to understand as possible. It's been a very long time since mainstream programmers have had to decipher or cut code directly.

The use of the "code" and "coding" words is a common mistake in our industry, and comes from mistaking the result with the origin.

Comment: Seems [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/code) (and probably other dictionaries) disagrees with you: code (verb, specialized [computing]): to write computer programs (= instructions):

Comment: Is *Morse code* (around for much longer than computers) used to hide or obscure messages? Some words have more than one meaning, and *code* is one of them.